# How to respond to a mouse click on a Shape

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a small functionality i which:

1. User can select any number of objects(like line,circle etc) to offset.
2. User would right-click the object they want to offset from vertically and be provided an enterable field to specify the offset distance.
3. Upon clicking an “OK” button from #2, the objects would offset starting from the center of the selected object and space by the specified distance until all selected objects have been placed.

I'm new to Swing Framework, I have learned how to create objects and action listeners. Please help me in doing this.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Line extends JComponent {

   private final Point2D start, end;

    public Line( Point2D start, Point2D end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouse clicked");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0F));
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(start,end));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question and share your code. Show what you did and where you have difficulties.

Comment: @c0der - Hello Dear, Thank you for your response and greet. I have uploaded my code. For the lines created can you please tell me How to Offset to Space these line objects. User can select any number of objects(like line,circle etc) to offset.
User would right-click the object they want to offset from vertically and be provided an enterable field to specify the offset distance.
Upon clicking an “OK” button from #2, the objects would offset starting from the center of the selected object and space by the specified distance until all selected objects have been placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you solve a problem by dividing it to smaller problems. 
First thing you would need is to identify a mouse click on a line.
One way to achieve it is to have a custom component like this one:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Line extends JComponent {

   private final Point2D start, end;

    public Line( Point2D start, Point2D end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouse clicked");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0F));
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(start,end));
    }
}
```

Try to use it to draw a line on a `JPanel`.
Try to draw several lines and identify which was clicked. 
After that try to move the clicked lines.

Comment: Thanks C0der. But as I mentioned I have learned how to write the listeners. Next I will do is write pop-up handler to accept the distance it should be moved like -                          
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number");
input1 = Integer.parseInt(input);

Comment: Next the main thing which I'm not getting is how to determine the location of the clicked object and move it to the new location which we get as an input from the user.

Comment: **"**_I mentioned I have learned how to write the listeners_**"** I don't see it in the code posted. Please show how do you listen to a line represented as `g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(59.2d, 99.8d, 419.1d, 99.8d))`

Comment: Im sorry I dint mean to offend you. I just started learning swings since one week. And I want to know how we move objects from one point to the other. Please help me in knowing how to do this. It will be really helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: No problem at all. I was not offended. I did try to help by posting what I believe can be a starting point. I also suggested how to take it forward.